# No such file or directory: '/django_logs/documents_utils.log'

Tags: python, django, exception

I pulled repository after two months and after a lot of changes, and after start project I met this problem, and don't know how to solve it. plz help me =(

```
   Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x7f5d6c15d578>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/sabo/projects/envs/halyk/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
        fn(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/sabo/projects/envs/halyk/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
        autoreload.raise_last_exception()
      File "/home/sabo/projects/envs/halyk/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 249, in raise_last_exception
        six.reraise(*_exception)
      File "/home/sabo/projects/envs/halyk/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
        fn(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/sabo/projects/envs/halyk/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 17, in setup
        configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
      File "/home/sabo/projects/envs/halyk/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/log.py", line 71, in configure_logging
        logging_config_func(logging_settings)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 794, in dictConfig
        dictConfigClass(config).configure()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 576, in configure
        '%r: %s' % (name, e))
    ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'utils_log_file': [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/django_logs/documents_utils.log'
```

**UPDATE**
And there my settings.py file where in Loggins added this path, and path it's show location into server, and how and where I can add it to start my project local?

```
LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': False,
'formatters': {
    'verbose': {
        'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s path: %(pathname)s module: %(module)s method: %(funcName)s  row: %(lineno)d message: %(message)s'
    },
    'simple': {
        'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
    },
},
'filters': {
    'require_debug_true': {
        '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue',
    },
    'require_debug_false': {
        '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
    }
},
'handlers': {
    'mail_admins': {
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
        'class': 'utils.handlers.MainAdminEmailHandler',
        'formatter': 'verbose',
    },
    'utils_log_file': {
        'level': 'INFO',
        'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
        'filename': '/django_logs/documents_utils.log',
        'maxBytes': 1024*1024*15, # 15MB
        'backupCount': 10,
        'formatter': 'verbose'
    },
    'console': {
        'level': 'INFO',
        'filters': ['require_debug_true'],
        'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        'formatter': 'simple'
    },
},
'loggers': {
    'django': {
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'propagate': True,
    },
    'django.request': {
        'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'propagate': True,
    },
    'utils': {
        'handlers': ['utils_log_file', 'mail_admins'],
        'level': 'INFO',
    },
    'documents': {
        'handlers': ['utils_log_file', 'mail_admins'],
        'level': 'INFO',
    },
}
```

Comment: Your logged is configured to log to that path. It does not exist.

Comment: @KlausD. where I need to create it, because how I said above, code was changed by another people, and I just have started it now. Can you suggest me something where I have to create it?

Comment: The expected path is `/django_logs/documents_utils.log`. The folderis kind of strange and does not match any best practice. You will even need root permissions to create it, so you might want to reconfigure the logging in the settings.

Comment: @KlausD. how to I can change it to start it local? and idea?

Comment: It's hard to tell you how to change the code you did not show.

Comment: @KlausD. now I added it can you look?

Comment: And you really don't see where to change the logging file name in there?

Comment: @KlausD. I see it but without changing it, can I make something like DEBUG mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, I solved this problem my self by adding this part

```
if not os.path.exists('/django_logs/documents_utils.log'):
    del LOGGING['handlers']['utils_log_file']
    del LOGGING['loggers']['utils']
    del LOGGING['loggers']['documents']
```